# scale an image to fit TOP and RIGHT in android ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, image-scaling

I use an `ImageView`, I **want** the source image to fit to the **TOP** and **RIGHT**.

FitEnd scaling fits **BOTTOM** and **RIGHT**
all other scale `enums` don't help much as well

any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="top|right">
   <ImageView
       android:scaleType="fitEnd"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This should get you the intended result.

Comment: This is a poor answer because the code is scrappy (has inconsistent use of double quotes) and the short explanatory paragraph provides little illumination.

Comment: @CarlosP I guess you forgot to read that it is a psuedo code. I do not believe in spoon feeding answers and expect some effort from the other side.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you are looking for the fitStart or, in code, `setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);`

Using that you could simply wrap the image in a layout wrapper that is aligned to the right, such as a RelativeLayout with `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Just use scaleType = MATRIX

e.g:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="%wanted width%"
    android:layout_height="%wanted height%"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="%your src%" />
```